# http to https causing redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I wish to forward all visitors to my site to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. Whatever they request, I want to server over HTTPS.

I've tried adding this to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But it just causes a redirect loop. I'm guessing RewriteCond isn't functioning as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Indeed it does. Thanks!